# Fill nan based on conditions from other columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to fill None values with values from activity_station.
Data is as follow and i created some columns to make conditioning easier.

```
Shift_id    activity_name   activity_id activity_begin_time activity_end_time   activity_station    shift   code    day
0   123 start   D01-MCK-DI  09:00   09:05   None    D01 MCK DI
1   123 work    D01-MCK-DI  09:05   12:00   Za      D01 MCK DI
2   123 drive   D01-MCK-DI  12:00   12:30   Ro      D01 MCK DI
3   184 start   D01-MV-DI   09:00   09:05   None    D01 MV  DI
4   184 work    D01-MV-DI   09:05   12:00   Ca      D01 MV  DI
5   184 drive   D01-MV-DI   12:00   12:30   None    D01 MV  DI
```

Load de data if you need:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Shift_id' :[ 123,123,123,184,184,184],
    'activity_name':['start','work','drive','start','work','drive'],
    'activity_id' : ['D01-MCK-DI','D01-MCK-DI','D01-MCK-DI','D01-MV-DI','D01-MV-DI','D01-MV-DI'],
    'activity_begin_time' : ['09:00','09:05','12:00','09:00','09:05','12:00'],
    'activity_end_time' : ['09:05','12:00','12:30','09:05','12:00','12:30'],
    'activity_station' : ['None', 'Za','Ro','None', 'Ca','None']})

df[['shift','code','day']] = df['activity_id'].str.split(pat="-", expand=True)
```

IF MV has a None value on the column activity_station

Then Look where shift and day of MV and  MCK are the same and assign the acitivity_station value of MCK to the None value of MV

I tried some IF else return statement but no succes after all.

The results should come out like this:

```
    Shift_id    activity_name   activity_id activity_begin_time activity_end_time   activity_station    shift   code    day
0   123 start   D01-MCK-DI  09:00   09:05   None    D01 MCK DI
1   123 work    D01-MCK-DI  09:05   12:00   Za      D01 MCK DI
2   123 drive   D01-MCK-DI  12:00   12:30   Ro      D01 MCK DI
3   184 start   D01-MV-DI   09:00   09:05   None    D01 MV  DI
4   184 work    D01-MV-DI   09:05   12:00   Ca      D01 MV  DI
5   184 drive   D01-MV-DI   12:00   12:30   Ro      D01 MV  DI
```

Comment: And should this generalise for multiple codes? Ans also are the amount of items where MCK the same as where MV?

Comment: it should, the number of MCK is equal to MV

Comment: I see `pandas` tagged, can we not use `np.where` ?

Comment: I edited my post. It does not have to be pandas necessarily

Comment: we can use `where` from `numpy` on `pandas` dataframes for conditional output. [refer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: You shouldn't have removed `pandas` tag here.

Comment: BTW, `np.where` is messy.

Comment: There are cases where MV values are known and i dont want them to be replaced. I edit this in my post

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need one more grouping column in order to achieve your desired output. You are currently describing grouping by both `shift` and `day`, but this still only produces a single group, so I am assuming that you also intend to group by `activity_name`. If this is the case, then you can use `transform()` after replacing the `None` values in your dataframe with `np.nan` (i.e. `NaN`):

```
df['activity_station'] = df.groupby(['shift','day','activity_name'])['activity_station'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

This produces your desired output:

```
   Shift_id activity_name activity_id activity_begin_time activity_end_time  \
0       123         start  D01-MCK-DI               09:00             09:05   
1       123          work  D01-MCK-DI               09:05             12:00   
2       123         drive  D01-MCK-DI               12:00             12:30   
3       184         start   D01-MV-DI               09:00             09:05   
4       184          work   D01-MV-DI               09:05             12:00   
5       184         drive   D01-MV-DI               12:00             12:30   

  activity_station shift code day  
0              NaN   D01  MCK  DI  
1               Za   D01  MCK  DI  
2               Ro   D01  MCK  DI  
3              NaN   D01   MV  DI  
4               Ca   D01   MV  DI  
5               Ro   D01   MV  DI
```

Comment: I don't want to group by activity_name because it can be different in other rows

Comment: Im thinking to use a for loop to iterate over data points and fill because imagine this set is larger. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You need to clarify how you are identifying `Ro` as the value that is used to fill the blank cell...it is not clear from your original question.

Comment: It can be identified by looking at the activity_begin_time and activity_end_time, MV and MCK would be doing an activity at the same time but not necessarily doing the same activity.

Comment: ....then how do you explain `Za` and `Ca`, since they have the same `shift`, `day`, `activity_begin_time` and `activity_end_time`?

Comment: shift, day, activity_begin_time and activity_end_time means its a team that has same shift and doing same tasks on same day and doing same acitivity at the same time but in different places, so shift_id is unique per person.